# Slugify selection

Tags: vimscript, vim

For the purpose of writing MarkDown documentation, I wanted to extend Vim with the ability to slugify selected text and to replace it with an anchor URL. The idea is to copy/paste a heading and use it to create index.

Example: say I have this text:

```markdown
Some header
---

The text.
```

I want to copy `Some header` to the beginning of the doc, select it, and easily turn it into `[Some text](#some-text)`.

What I came up with is this:

```
" Slugify selection
function Slugify(text)
    let result = substitute(a:text, ".*", "\\L&", "")
    let result = substitute(result, "[^a-z]\\+", "-" ,"g")
    return result
endfunction
command -range Slug :<line1>,<line2>s/\%V.*\%V./\=Slugify(submatch(0))/
command -range Slurl :<line1>,<line2>s/\%V.*\%V./\="[" . submatch(0) . "](#" . Slugify(submatch(0)) . ")"/
```

Usage:

1. Select text.
2. Type `:Slurl` for the whole anchor URL thing or `:Slug` to just slugify the selected text.

It seems to work fine for me, but I am a complete n00b with Vimscript (only started with it to get this working). Remarks and improvements would be quite welcome.

A minor side-question: is there an easy way to remove the selection or redefine it to match only the part inside `[...]` when done with `Slurl`?